# Let $X$ be a topological space. Let $Y$ be a dense subset of $X$. Let $Z$ be subspace of $X$ which satisfies $Y⊂Z⊂X$. If $Z$ is open, $Z＝X$?

Tags: general-topology, geometry

Let $X$ be a topological space.
Let $Y$ be a dense subset of $X$.
Let $Z$ be subspace of $X$ which satisfies $Y⊂Z⊂X$.
If $Z$ is open, $Z＝X$?

If $Z$ is closed, closure of $Z$ is contained in $X$ because closure of $Z$ is smallest closed subset which contains $Z$. But what about $Z$ is open?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $Y$ is open we cannot say that $X=Y$. Example: $X$ the reals, usual topology, $Y =\Bbb Q$ which is dense and $Z = \Bbb R\setminus \{\pi, \sqrt 2, 3\pi\}$ which is open.

Comment: R \{√2} is also example, right ?

Comment: @Nekojiru of course, but I like an example with $\pu$. We could also take $\Bbb R\setminus C$ where $C$ is a Cantor set with only irrationals. There are plenty of proper dense open sets.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Let $Y=Z=\{x:x=1/n\}$, where $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and $X=Z\cup\{0\}$, all with the topology induced from reals.

Comment: Do you mean the titled statement does not hold?

Comment: @Nekojiru $Z$ is open and dense in $X$, isn't it?